# Unable to Install Dependencies in Yarn: "Trouble with Network Connection" Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm encountering an issue with installing dependencies using Yarn. Previously, it was working fine, but all of a sudden, I'm unable to install any dependencies. Even when trying to install a lightweight package like axios with yarn add axios, I'm getting the following error:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/@mui%2fstyled-engine-sc: tunneling socket could not be established, cause =connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Folder\\Directory\projectfolder\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

It's worth noting that my network connection is stable because I was able to successfully install the same dependency on my Mac. I've tried several solutions to resolve the issue, including:

1. Uninstalling Yarn and reinstalling it.
2. Removing the .lock files.
3. Changing multiple network connections.
4. Using the `--network-timeout 100000` flag.
5. Running the following commands:

```
     yarn config delete https-proxy
     yarn config delete proxy
    
    yarn config get https-proxy
    yarn config get proxy
```

Despite these attempts, I'm still facing the same error. Any guidance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check if the windows defender firewall is blocking network access for node?

Comment: @Nirmal Kumar I completely turned off my windows defender firewall. But still same issue